# Cloudwatch logs on terminal

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-cloudwatch

I am using AWS Lambda for my application. For logs, I have to see in UI only, which I really don't like to see. Is there a way that I could connect to Cloudwatch logs locally and then see the logs by the tail command? Or if I could access Cloudwatch server to see logs? Basically, I wanted to see logs on my terminal. If there is any way to do that, please let me know.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use AWS CLI to get your logs in real time. See: [get-log-events](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/logs/get-log-events.html)

AWS doesn't provide a functionality where you can tail the log. There are few 3rd party tools you can use. I have used [jorgebastida/awslogs](https://github.com/jorgebastida/awslogs) which was sufficient for my needs.

**Update** 02/25/2021: Thanks to @adavea, I just checked and found AWS has added a new feature to tail the CW logs.

[aws.logs.tail](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/logs/tail.html)

`--follow` (boolean) Whether to continuously poll for new logs.

Comment: The aws cli team actually added a --follow flag somewhat recently which allows for tailing, e.g. 

aws logs tail --follow "/aws/lambda/somelambda"

Answer (score 2):

On my linux/macosx/cygwin console, this will give you the latest log file.

Substitute $1 with your group name

```
echo aws logs get-log-events --log-group-name /aws/lambda/$1 --log-stream-name `aws logs describe-log-streams --log-group-name /aws/lambda/$1 --max-items 1 --descending --order-by LastEventTime | grep logStreamName | cut -f2 -d: | sed 's/,//'|sed 's/\"/'\''/g'`| sh -
```

Note that you will need to install awscli (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-install.html)

I wrapped the above in a **sh** function

```
function getcw() {
    echo aws logs get-log-events --log-group-name /aws/lambda/$1 --log-stream-name `aws logs describe-log-streams --log-group-name /aws/lambda/$1 --max-items 1 --descending --order-by LastEventTime | grep logStreamName | cut -f2 -d: | sed 's/,//'|sed 's/\"/'\''/g'`| sh -
}
```

and can view the latest log for my logs in **chai-lambda-trigger** using the command

$ **getcw chai-lambda-trigger**

If you wanted just the tail of the output, you could do

$ **getcw chai-lambda-trigger | tail**

Answer (score 1):

There are some command line tools like cwtail and awslogs that do a -f follow tail.

Your other option is a free tool I created called SenseLogs that does a live tail in your browser. It is 100% browser based. See https://github.com/sensedeep/senselogs/blob/master/README.md for details.